# Polymorphic Association Rails : Different primary_keys types (id & uuid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphism, uuid

I would like to define a polymorphic table. My problem being that one table's primary_key is of type `uuid(string)` and the other `id(integer)`.
I thought maybe having a `model_able_id` and a `model_able_uuid` varying depending on the `model_type` but i cannot figure that out and it would probably break tons of activerecord features for polymorphic.

Some other things i have thought of would be to use STI, but i'm still confused, and, of course, i could migrate ids to uuids and that'd sort me out (but i'd rather not).

Comment: as you said you can use uuid in both the models, this seems a good solution.

Comment: Just for the record, these are related issues on official rails repo: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33407 https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33525

Answer (score 5):

Specify the type for the (polymorphic) foreign key in the options. Change `:string` to `:uuid` if required.

```
create_table :table_name do |t|
  t.references :target, type: :string, polymorphic: true, null: false
end
```

Then both string and integer `target_id`s are acceptable.

Check the [API docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-references).

Comment: For Postgres, `type: :uuid` works for me.

Comment: Integer ids do not seem to work with the string type (Rails 7.0.8).

Answer (score 1):

Was facing same issue, there is no official solution yet, these two issues are open in rails repo about this:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33407

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33525

There is [a suggestion in one of these issues](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33525#issuecomment-410964327), it didn't work for me(it was generating both joins, the default one generated by rails which causes failure and one which i defined).

I ended up not using association at all, i defined a method to get the actual records properly with a custom query. I didn't need `dependent: destroy` otherwise i could have defined a before_destroy method too.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. My solution modifies the type of the `_id` field to string.

```
def change
  add_reference :ratings, :rater, polymorphic: true, index: true
  change_column :ratings, :rater_id, :string
end
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Rails join is not casting properly the uuid to string in my case. When i try to access the association

Answer (score 0):

One way of a few to do this is to have more than one polymorphic class with the same purpose that duck type the same, one for ids and one for strings. I'll demonstrate with this `Commentable` concern.

```
# bigint id migration
create_table :comments do |t|
  t.references :commentable, polymorphic: true, null: true
  ...
end

# string id migration
create_table :string_id_comments do |t|
  t.references :commentable, type: :string, polymorphic: true, null: true
  ...
end
```

Define models for `StringIdComments` and `Comments`. They could share code through a concern or through extension. The `Commentable` concern now needs to decide which to use:

```
module Commentable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    if columns_hash[primary_key].type == :integer
      has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
    else
      has_many :comments, as: :commentable, class_name: 'StringIdComments', dependent: :destroy
    end
  end
end
```

If you wished to query through `Comment`, this has the downside of having two tables which could be eliminated by using these as through tables to the actual comment. I haven't tested, but it might also be solved by having two keys in a single polymorphic class, a string and a bigint, and specifying the key in the `has_`.